# Proof Verification: If $a | x$ and $b | y$, then $ab | 2xy$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility

I have an exercise stating:

> Assume $a,b,x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$. Prove that if $a | x$ and $b | y$, then $ab | 2xy$.

My proof is:

By assumption, there is $k_1 , k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ak_1 = x$ and $bk_2 = y$. Therefore, $2xy = 2ak_1 bk_2 = ab(2k_1 k_2)$ where $2k_1 k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$, and so $ab|2xy$.

Is this proof correct, and if so are there any ways in which it can be made clearer?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes it is. I dont see how you could make this clearer ..

Comment: from where comes the factor $2$?

Comment: Remember $$a|x$$ then we get $$x=ka$$ with some intergers $k$

Comment: Perfectly clear and straightforward.  "from where comes the factor 2" ???? why does it have to come from anywhere?  It's part of the question; not the conclusion.

Comment: Okay.  one stylistic improvement.  "By assumption, there is"  Replace this with "By **definition**" That is a much stronger statement.  I have a feeling being more forceful would do you some good.  You gave a perfect and direct proof but had doubts in question.  I don't see why you had doubts.

Comment: Oh!  You *DO* have an error/typo in $2xy = ak_1bk_2 = ab(2k_12k_2)$.  In the middle term the "$ak_1bk_2$" should be "$2ak_1bk_2$".   That was obviously a typo.